# Linking error while declaring stack in C++

Tags: c++, templates, tree, stack

```
 #include <iostream> 
 #include <stack>

 using namespace std;

template <typename T>

class Node {

        T data;
        public:
        Node<T>* left;
        Node<T>* right;
        Node(T data) {
            this->data = data;
            left = right = NULL;
       }  
       T getData() {
            return data;
       }
};

//Inorder traversal using iterative

template<typename T>

void printInorder(Node<T>* root) {

        stack<Node<T>*> s;  // Getting linking error here************
        Node<T>* cur = root;
        s.push(cur);
        while (cur != NULL && !s.empty()) {
            while (cur != NULL) {
                cur = cur->left;
                if(cur != NULL) s.push(cur);            
            }

            cur = s.top();
            s.pop();
            cout << cur->getData() << " ";
            cur = cur->right;
        }
}

int main() {

        Node<int>* root = new Node<int>(1);
        root->left = new Node<int>(2);
        root->right = new Node<int>(3);
        root->left->left = new Node<int>(4);
        root->left->right = new Node<int>(5);
        printInorder<int>(root);
        cin.get();
        return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp___invalid_parameter
> referenced in function "void * __cdecl
> std::_Allocate_manually_vector_aligned<struct
> std::_Default_allocate_traits>(unsigned int)"
> (??$_Allocate_manually_vector_aligned@U_Default_allocate_traits@std@@@std@@YAPAXI@Z)  DataStructure   C:\Users\rkaqrb\source\repos\DataStructure\Traversal(Tree).obj  1
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, if you have spaces in your includes, like  `#include < stack >`, you need to change them to `#include <stack>`

Comment: My actual code is not having any spaces #include <stack>. did you tried to run code linking error is not coming for you?

Comment: I too cannot reproduce this, using clang 9 or gcc 9

Comment: The problem is something to do with the way your compiler is setup and/or invoked. Specifically, linker errors _cannot_ be internal to a single translation unit like the one you've posted. So, you'll have to explain how you're building and what your build config or project look like if you want any help with that.

Comment: I am using visual c++ 2019, anyone please suggest if any setting i have to change?

Comment: @Useless Surely they can be? In the case of something like templates where the code is designed not to link for invalid instantatons

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong here with stack, when i comment out stack declaration section there will not be any linking error.

Comment: @LonesomeParadise I guess so - I was thinking in terms of needing to link _to_ something rather than the single translation unit simply being incomplete.